# Once an exception is thrown, it shouldn't ideally go to a TearDown/ aftertest

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, nunit, extent

I'm using the **NUnit** framework. If my test-case failed with an exception like a timeout or any other exceptions. After the test it should go to `[Teardown]` but it is not going struck there abort the operation.

> Agenda is trying to log the errors and capture it to the extent
>   report.

```
       [Obsolete]
    [Test]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        try
        {
           ...Throwing exceptions
          }
        catch(Exception ex)
         {
        // throw new NotImplementedException();
           // Assert.Fail("No exception was thrown");
           // AfterTest(); 
          }
         }

       [TearDown]
    public void AfterTest()
    {
        try
        {


            var status = TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome.Status;
            var stacktrace = " " +TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.StackTrace + " ";
            var errorMessage = TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Message;
            Status logstatus;
            switch (status)
            {
                case TestStatus.Failed:
                    logstatus = Status.Fail;
                    string screenShotPath = Capture(driver, TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name);
                    _test.Log(logstatus, "Test ended with " +logstatus + " – " +errorMessage);
                    _test.Log(logstatus, "Snapshot below: " +_test.AddScreenCaptureFromPath(screenShotPath));
                    break;
                case TestStatus.Skipped:
                    logstatus = Status.Skip;
                    _test.Log(logstatus, "Test ended with " +logstatus);
                    break;
                default:
                    logstatus = Status.Pass;
                    _test.Log(logstatus, "Test ended with " +logstatus);
                    break;
            }
            driver.Quit();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw (e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "After the test it should go to [Teardown] but it is not going struck there abort the operation"? So it is not going to the Teardown? Or it is going to the Teardown and you don't want it to? Or is it going to the Teardown and then the test hangs while the Teardown is executing?

Comment: Assuming that the process should move to  `[Teardown]` annotation. Then you should not use the `try-catch` inside the test annotations because Test annotations provide test results based on the exception so try by removing `try-catch` blocks

Comment: @GregBurghardt It is not going to Teardown, it was aborted in the [Test] once exception triggered.

Answer (score 1):

> Assuming that the process should move to `[Teardown]` annotation.

Then you should not use the `try-catch` inside the test annotations because Test annotations provide test results based on the **Exception** so try by removing `try-catch` blocks

**Reference:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/111270/10858089